# Implementation of chrono library

Tags: c++, time, cpu-architecture

In C++, we can use `chrono` library to handle the time. And I think it's asynchronous with CPU clock. I mean,`chrono::seconds(1)` is real 1 second and not relative with how many instruction was executed during this duration.  Am I right?

If I'm right, how it works at low level? Is there any timer hardware works asynchronously with CPU clock in general modern computer architecture?

Comment: Your question is unclear. If you wonder how a *specific* piece of code works, post it.

Comment: As I understand it, the OP is asking how the system calls or other mechanisms underlying time-related calls such as those offered by `std::chrono` are implemented by the OS and underlying hardware.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your typical modern computer has two ways to tell time, and these two ways help each other under the hood.

1. There is typically a [Time Stamp Counter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Stamp_Counter) which is nothing but a special register that gets incremented with each clock cycle.  The computer also knows its own cycle time, and so that count of cycles can be converted into a physical time duration such as nanoseconds.  This is ultimately what is used when an OS supplies a "real time clock", known in C++11 and later as `std::chrono::steady_clock`.
2. Additionally modern computers understand and participate in a [Network Time Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol).  This is essentially an organized way for one computer to ask another computer what the current UTC time is.  A computer can use this to find out the current time, and then use its local [Time Stamp Counter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Stamp_Counter) to translate that into a UTC time at a later time.  A computer may use the [NTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol) several times a day to keep its local time keeping accurate.  In C++11 and later this is accessed via `std::chrono::system_clock`.

Decades ago, personal computers did not participate in [NTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol), and instead asked the human who booted up the computer the current time and date, and then used its onboard [TSC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Stamp_Counter) to keep local time.

**Update**

Please read [Peter Cordes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/224132/peter-cordes) comments below for details that I glossed over.

Comment: x86's TSC works as a real time clock because it counts *reference cycles*, not core clock cycles that actually control instructions moving through the pipe.  Turbo / powersaving change the core clock, and it stops when the CPU is sleeping, but the reference clock doesn't (on CPUs with the `nonstop_tsc` feature, which is everything for several years now).

Comment: Decades ago, there wasn't a TSC built-in to the CPU, and the CPU would write/read I/O registers of a timer chip to find the real time.  Using `rdtsc` as a low-overhead time source is very nice, and avoids even having to switch into the kernel for a `gettimeofday`, let alone talk to external hardware.  (`rdtsc` was introduced before CPU power-saving was really a thing, so it worked as a performance counter *and* as a real-time clock.  In some early chips with power-saving, it still counted actual cycles and didn't work as a time source.)

Comment: It is probably worth noting that the other non-TSC time sources (such as the various hardware clocks) are still often used as a base for various time routines: a typical approach is to use such clocks for the "coarse" time and then add the offset from the coarse time based on reading the TSC. For example, the coarse time could be written every kernel "tick", and then the TSC is used to determine how much time has passed since then.

Comment: Among other things, this keeps time roughly in sync with the "more accurate", but slower to read real-time clocks. Note that "more accurate" here often means actually more precise (since the implementation of the TSC relies on details that are in tension with total accuracy) but also more accurate since the real-time clocks get the various adjustments such as NTP speedup/slowdown (this applies to some, but not all of the clocks exposed by the OS - for example the _RAW clocks omit it).